# complex analysis line integral and limit

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

this is my first time writing in this forum, so i apologize in advance for any spelling or coding mistakes. :)

the following question is from my complex analysis course:

let there be 2 polynomials P(z) & Q(z), we know that (deg(P)+2)$\le$(deg(Q))

$\gamma$:[$\theta$1,$\theta$2]--->C  where 0<$\theta1$<$\theta2$<2$\pi$

$\gamma$(t)= R$\bullet$e^(it)

show that : $\lim_{x\to inf} \int_\gamma\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}$ = 0

so i was wondering if there is a theorem in complex analysis that allows me to switch between the limit and the integral,because that would solve the problem i guess. if not i'd be happy if someone could point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [LM theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma): for $\;0<R\in\Bbb R\;$ big enough:

$$\left|\oint_\gamma\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}dz\right|\le2\pi R\max_{z\in\gamma}\frac{|P(z)|}{|Q(z)|}\le\frac{2\pi R\cdot R^n}{R^{n+2}}=\frac{2\pi}R\xrightarrow[R\to\infty]{}0$$

Comment: wow so simple :), thanks!!